# Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox 23 - how to turn off JavaScript?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, javascript

My browser updated yesterday and today I've noticed that the option to turn off JavaScript is no longer there. Did they relocate it somewhere? Help.

Comment: Known bug? See [Bug 873709](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=873709) on bugzilla.

Comment: Also read [Checkboxes that kill your product](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KdBiKKO8OOwJ:limi.net/checkboxes-that-kill/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option was intentionally removed in Firefox 23, on the logic that blocking all javascript makes a significant fraction of sites unusable, and so blocking all javascript, everywhere, is seldom desirable behaviour. As the bug report linked by edwin notes, this was a controversial change.

You can blanket disable javascript by going to page `about:config` and setting the key `javascript.enabled` to `false`.

However, if you want to block javascript an extension like [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) which gives you fine grained control over which scripts run is a better choice.

Comment: Great feature. I am pissed!